# Meaning of after a person

Tags: word-usage

What does the 'after' mean in this sentence?

- They called the baby John, after Bill's grandfather.

Comment: This question is answered by a previous thread [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188449/named-for-vs-named-after).

Comment: @Margana The following answers do add to the explanation, but this question does need to show signs of research ("named after" is easily found).

Comment: The construction is _name `X` after/for `Y`_, which means that `Y` is the source of the name of `X`. It's often used in the passive, as in _Jehoboam is/was named after/for his grandfather_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In honor of as a celebration of or expression of respect for.

**[CITE](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/after)**

Comment: Either reason might be true, but that's not what "after" means.  It means that Bill's grandfather was named John, and that's why the baby was named John.  Generally, it's honorary, but the reason is immaterial.  The baby may have been named John out of obligation, and he should grow up grateful that Grandpa wasn't named Jedediah.

Comment: Please cite the source.

Comment: @Kris: Cite added, per request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be noted that this is primarily a UK-English expression. The US version is more commonly, "They named the baby John, for Bill's grandfather."

[US readers please correct me if I'm inaccurate about this.]

> They called the baby John, after Bill's grandfather.

Taken literally, this means that Bill's grandfather was called John and the baby was given the same name **at a later date**.

I suspect that this is what gave rise to the usage in the first place, e.g.

*He was called Arthur and after him his son was called Arthur and after that his grandson was called Arthur.*  (invented by me)

The above sentence shows a *chronology*. However, as humans, we naturally infer that the repeated use of the same name is for a reason - it's not due to drawing names out of a hat.

Therefore "A was named after B" has come to mean "A was named after B for a reason" which in turn becomes "A was named in honour of B".

**Disclaimer**

I don't claim that my supposed etymology is strictly based in fact. Much research would be needed to back this up.  I provide it by way of explanation of the *meaning* of the phrase, as requested in the original post.

Comment: -1 What about "The baby takes after his grand father"?

Comment: @Kris - I don't know - what about it? You tell me! :-)